# Cannot resolve method equals(java.lang.Long)

Tags: java, equals

The following code gives error (with IDEA) while I think it shouldn't.

```
Long[] a = {0L, 0L};
Long[] b = {1L, 1L};
if((a[0] + a[1]).equals(b[1]))
    System.out.println("Equal");
```

Says `cannot resolve method equals(java.lang.Long)`. But it works well with `if(a[0].equals(b[0]))`. I thought that plus operator would return a Long object.

Why does it seem like it doesn't return a `Long` object, and how are we able to use `Long c = a[0] + a[1]` if it doesn't return a Long object? Or why can't we use `equals` like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it seem like it doesn't return a `Long` object?

[15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)  tells us that:

> *Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands.*
>
> *The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted type of its operands.*

And [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)  tells us that:

> *If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion.*

What this means is that the result of `Long + Long` is `long` and we can't call methods on a primitive type.

> And how are we able to use `Long c = a[0] + a[1]` if it doesn't return a `Long` object?

For `Long c = a[0] + a[1]`, the `long` is boxed by the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`a[0] + a[1]` are added as primitive types and are not [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) (primitives do not have methods, hence compile time error). You need to either explicitly wrap them into an object:

```
(new Long(a[0] + a[1])).equals(b[1])
```

...or rely on the `unboxing` of `b[1]` into a primitive type

```
a[0] + a[1] == b[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace this line:

```
if((a[0] + a[1]).equals(b[1]))
```

for this:

```
if(a[0] + a[1] == b[1])
```

**EDIT:**
Yes, you're right - equals can't take sum of longs as parameter, from other answers I can see that it's because they are primitive values. Good to know that, we learn everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(a[0] + a[1])
```

results in **primitive** `long` and not in reference type `java.lang.Long`.

If you're trying to use a member of a primitive type, that results in a compile time error.

You could use autoboxing, to convert the result of the addition back to `Long` like this:

```
((Long)(a[0] + a[1])).equals(b[1])
```

`Long c = (a[0] + a[1]);` does something like that "internally", i.e. actually works like this:

```
Long c = (Long)((long)a[0] + (long)a[1]);
```

You could also simply unbox `b[1]`:

```
(a[0] + a[1]) == b[1]
```